# 240 volt patio heater on timer won't turn off

Tags: 240v, heater, 120-240v

We had a 240V ceiling mounted patio heater installed 10 years ago and last year the timer switch started buzzing loudly when the heater was turned on.  I swapped out the timer switch with what I thought was the identical model and wired it the same way.  When the timer was turned on the heater worked fine but would not shut off until I went back to the breaker.  It is wired with the black wire hot at 120 volts going to the switch, the white wire hot at 120 volts tied together to the heater and bypassing the switch, white wire from switch tied to ground and all other grounds tied together.  That is how I photographed the original install.  I then tried to tie the white switch wire to the two white hot wires and the heater turned on without the switch and again, would not turn off.  I have read that I might need to introduce a relay into this setup to get the timer to work properly.  Before I go that route I was wondering how they got the original timer to work without one.

Comment: How about some pictures of the box, timer and timer diagram.

Comment: Also, include that pic of the original install, just to be sure.

Comment: "white wire from switch tied to ground" This is not correct wiring. You should not have a white wire tied to ground for this type of circuit. What size circuit breaker is feeding this circuit? Is the breaker feeding this circuit a 2-pole breaker?